# Extract htm text for differents tags in imacros

Tags: imacros

I want to extract the htm text for a particular tags, so [here](https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Navi-Mumbai&BudgetMin=50-Lacs&BudgetMax=60-Lacs) is the link for which I want to extract their htm text
I use this tag to extract the entire htm text for a particular record

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=div ATTR=class:m-srp-card<SP>SRCard&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
```

So by just changing the `POS=?` number I get the htm text for every record, but in this case the attribute `class:m-srp-card<SP>SRCard` changes for different position. for example in when POS=3 it tags 4th record instead of 3rd.
Is there any alternative by which I can just change the `POS` number and get the htm record?

Thanks

Domnick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the link you provided, the problem is with the `attribute selector` as you mentioned, the reason you are facing this issue is because it exactly checks for the class in the div to be `m-srp-card<SP>SRCard` but in some of the elements there are other classes which are present, my solution for this will be to add a wildcard (`*`) at the end of the classes, so that it is flexible and allows other classes to be present.

```
VERSION BUILD=1001 RECORDER=CR
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=div ATTR=class:m-srp-card<SP>SRCard* EXTRACT=HTM
```

I have also setup a loop which can be rerun to iterate through the divs, also included the second line which will handle cases where the particular tag is not present in the html.

Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

Comment: Its the `*` thing that did the trick and that's what exactly I was looking for. Thanks much.